# Not able to access Selenium.SetSpeed() method

Tags: selenium

Not able to access any methods in the Selenium class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class login 
{
public Selenium selenium;
public SeleniumServer seleniumserver;

@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
{
        seleniumserver=new SeleniumServer();
        selenium=new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*iexplore","http://");
        selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testlogin() throws Exception
        {
selenium.setSpeed("2000"); 
}
}
```

when i say selenium dot,the intellisense is not working,and not able to access any of the methods.
{

Comment: Have you added selenium-java.jar to your build path?

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any URL. `selenium.setSpeed('1000')` provide 1 sec time delay between two selenium command. I dont know what you are trying to do.